# (Canada) How likely/unlikely is it to get accepted to a direct entry PhD program?

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, masters, supervision

I am now torn apart between leaving Canada to do a masters program in a foreign country, which will put a huge financial burden on me, I don't even know if I can afford it, and I would also become isolated from my family and would likely have to break up with my GF.

I also could spend the next year doing research with a professor at a local university while also working, but I am sick of working, all I want is to do research, all I want is to learn math.

If I can get accepted into a direct entry PhD program, delaying entrance is worth it, because I can start the program a year earlier. But if it's very unlikely, then I would have ruined my chance to get back on track into the only thing that really matters to me for trying to optimize for some less important (but still valuable) variables.

So in short, is it likely to get accepted into a direct entry PhD? I understand each institution, program and professor is different, and that it depends on the candidate, I just want a general idea.

Edit: 
I am considering it, but if I am going to do a masters anyway, from a purely academic perspective, there would be no reason to delay my studies and simply go to the foreign university. It would be much easier to justify and additional "GAP year" as a way to invest my time into improving my profile to be accepted into a PhD program directly and skip the masters alltogether, mostly because I know for a fact I want a PhD, I know for a fact I want to do research.

Direct entry simply means bachelors to PhD, i.e skipping the masters, currently the plan is next September (2020 not 2019).

I had a 3.67 GPA, however if we take away 4 japanese courses (that I tok out of interest) it's 3.72, 3.8 in CS courses, 3.98 in math courses (I have a pure math minor).

I did honours but did not publish the research (some non negligible additional work was needed to get it published and I graduated right then, then moved to a different city).

I am in a rush to start because that's all I wanted to do for the longest time, I let my family convince me to work for a while to see what the "real world is like", and after working and doing undergrad research, I understand with full clarity that I'd rather do research for 20k a year than work for 100k a year. I want to learn more math.

Comment: Ask the person you would like to supervise your PhD.

Comment: They said "there's no guarantee that you will get the position even if you do a good job, maybe I won't have the funding".

Which is fair, but there's other universities and supervisors I could also apply to and see what happens.

Comment: That's a better answer than you can get from Stack Exchange.

Comment: @Makogan Given your edits, I think you are worrying too much about a "gap year." Skipping your Masters might just mean you spend that much longer getting started in your PhD. The Masters is a good time to take advanced classes, learn to read papers, etc. Also, if you are starting with a CS background, I definitely would recommend a Masters if you're switching to Math. A Canadian Masters will help, not hinder, your research career.

Comment: I am not trying to switch into math, rather the kind of work I have been doing since my undergrad, is mathematical in nature (I have to work with parametric surfaces, calculuse, differential equations, statistics...) quite a bit. But my focus is still CS, i.e I want to do a CS PhD that involves a lot of math (still within the field I have been working so far which is computer graphics)

And it wouldn;t be a gap year, it would be two of them.

Comment: @Makogan if you're interested in Graphics, look at the UBC PhD Track Master's program. It's a master's program where you have the option to transfer to PhD after a year. UBC also has an excellent program for graphics. https://www.cs.ubc.ca/students/grad/prospective-grads/grad-programs/phd-track-msc-program

Comment: @jmite Thank you so much for this tip, this is awesome!

Comment: @Makogan if you're a Canadian citizen or PR then you should also definitely applying to the NSERC CGS-M scholarship.

Comment: @jmite Can I apply if I have a pending application for PR? (i.e I applied but have received no reply yet)

Comment: @makogan no clue. Google is your friend

Answer (score 4):

1. Is there any reason you're not considering a Canadian Master's program? They're usually funded, and doing a Master's is pretty standard before doing a PhD in Canada.
2. What do you mean by "direct entry"? If you mean starting this September, then your odds are quite low. If you mean "straight from Bachelor's to PhD" then that's a different story.
3. What are your grades like? Do you have any undergraduate research experience? Skipping the Master's is generally reserved for "exceptional students" in Canada, so your odds depend on how your Bachelor's went.

I know some schools have a "PhD Track Master's" where you start in a Master's and transfer to PhD after a year. Maybe that's for you?

Graduate studies is a long haul. Don't be in a rush to start it if it doesn't work for your life.

Comment: Good answer taking into account the Canadian system

Answer (score 1):

To answer the titular question: yes, direct entry from a BSc to a PhD definitely is possible. This may be anecdotal evidence, but I know several who pulled it off. In practice though, MASc to PhD is much more common. To go straight from a BSc to a PhD, the bar in terms of grades, previous research experience, publications etc is higher. From my anecdotal evidence, you will probably need an 'A' grade overall and previous publications.

In the end though, it is down to each individual department and more importantly each individual professor. If you can convince a professor to take you on and he has funding, he can vouch for you on the departmental level to help you secure the department-level scholarships needed provided you clear the minimum grade requirements (which are higher for BSc -> PhD than BSc -> MASc). Your best bet would be to ask about direct entry on a case by case basis by contacting professors you are interested in working with. I have found that professors are usually much more eager to take on PhD students rather than MASc students if they can help it. I speculate this is probably due to the fact that they will be able to get more work done tying a potential student down for 4 years than for two.

Joining at the masters level then subsequently switching to a PhD after a term or two is also possible and common from what I have heard as the previous poster pointed out.